# jquery listbox return what user selected

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i am using this demo:

http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/demo/v20/niceforms.html

i would like to know which values the user has selected.

```
<select size="4" name="languages[]" id="languages" multiple="multiple">

                    <option value="English">English</option>

                    <option value="French">French</option>

                    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>

                    <option value="Italian">Italian</option>

                    <option value="Chinese">Chinese</option>

                    <option value="Japanese">Japanese</option>

                    <option value="Russian">Russian</option>

                    <option value="Esperanto">Esperanto</option>

                </select>
```

the question is how do i return the values that were selected by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together a quick demo (using the select box structure from your example) here: http://jsfiddle.net/wp7sq/

So essentially, in my example I've created a simple function that gets *which* options the user selected, adds them to an array (just for convenience).  So from here, you can output it to a string, or search your array, or do whatever you want using JavaScript using that array.

The *relevant* section is commented in the sample, and here's the jQuery code from my example:

```
var selectedLanguages = new Array();
jQuery('#languages option:selected').each(function() {
    selectedLanguages.push(jQuery(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
ob = document.getElementById('languages'); 

for (var i = 0; i < ob.options.length; i++){
    if (ob.options[ i ].selected){     
      alert(ob.options[ i ].value); //Do something useful here
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#languages").value;`should work

Comment: thanks so much can you show me how i could pass this into my webform?

Comment: you could do an ajax call, but as probably what you want to do, is change the language of the page, you should use a server control that performs a postback when the control change. By the way, in a language menu, you should use the localized name of the language, for example `<option value="Spanish">Español</option>`

Comment: "languages" will not select anything (in the markup of the OP's example).  And I don't think **.value** is a valid jQuery method.

Comment: With this kind of small tasks, I find it better to skip jQuery. Native is faster. If you have to write more lines of code with any framework than native, the alarm goes off in my head..