# asp.net: run javascript on click?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

i have a form and a button a form:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="SubmitData"  />
```

i have a method in my c# program. the method is called `SubmitData`

however i would also like to run a javascript function on this button click as well. how do i do this?

here is my javascript function:

```
var selectedLanguages = new Array();
jQuery('#lstProblems option:selected').each(function() {
    selectedLanguages.push(jQuery(this).val());
});
```

i got it from here: [jquery listbox return what user selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409199/jquery-listbox-return-what-user-selected)

how do i run it ? do i have to put it in `<script></script>` and do some_Function(etc...) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use the `OnClientClick='myJsFunc();'`

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="SubmitData" OnClientClick="aaa()" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">

function aaa()
{
var selectedLanguages = new Array();
jQuery('#lstProblems option:selected').each(function() {
    selectedLanguages.push(jQuery(this).val());
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="SubmitData"  /> how do i modify this>?

Comment: <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="SubmitData" OnClientClick="JS function" />

Comment: @mid7 thank you!! perhaps you can help with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476329/asp-net-invalid-postback-or-callback-argument

Answer (score 3):

You can use OnClientClick event

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="Your javascript function" OnClick="SubmitData"  />
```

Answer (score 2):

Set up your server side event code the way it seems to be already, then in the Page_Load method of your code behind add the following line:

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick","yourJavascriptFunction();");
```

**EDIT**: To run the function from your edited question, simply create a function of the same name in your javascript file. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function yourJavascriptFunction()
{
var selectedLanguages = new Array();
jQuery('#lstProblems option:selected').each(function() {
    selectedLanguages.push(jQuery(this).val());
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: @j rose this is a beautiful answer  thanks so much can you see edited question please

Comment: @j rose thank you!! perhaps you can help with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476329/asp-net-invalid-postback-or-callback-argument