# ASP.NET Errors when PostBack Includes Modified List

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, postback

I am using JavaScript/jQuery to dynamically adding elements to a dropdown list on an WebForms page. This is working fine, but when I post the page back to the server, I get the following error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

I think I understand what is happening here: ASP.NET is verifying that the list is the same one that was originally served and detects that it has changed. This is a security feature because this indicates data is being submitted from a modified page.

However, in this case, the behavior is valid. And I would prefer not to disable this feature because it is a good security feature for the rest of my page.

Is there any way to tell ASP.NET to ignore only changes to this one list?

**EDIT:**

My code is in a Web User Control so I thought it might be acceptable to set the `EnableEventValidation` property for the control. Unfortunately, it appears this property is only available for the entire page.

Comment: How are you posting back?

Comment: Just by clicking a server button control.

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: What code? It's a button. Clicking it posts back automatically. It's not my code that causes this error, it's ASP.NET.

Comment: @JonathanWood Something else is going on. I just tried to recreate a basic scenario (created a dropdownlist with a few ListItem elements server-side, added a few more OPTION elements client-side and posted back via button click) and got no errors

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: Thanks for checking that. Perhaps I don't understand what is happening afterall. Just to confirm, this is on a WebForms page, correct?

Comment: Usually this happens when you do a custom call to a `__doPostBack('ControlID', 'someArguments')` any chance you're doing something like this somewhere?

Comment: It doesn't appear so. The markup is `<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Save and Return Later" ID="ReturnLaterButton" Style="margin-left: 250px;" />` and I'm not seeing any JavaScript that references this element.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: In your example, does setting the page property `EnableEventValidation="true"` make any difference?

Comment: Just tried that as well, still no errors. On postback simple original server-side dropdown is rebuild, losing client-side items. I believe `EnableEventValidation="true"` is a default setting when ommited

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: Yes, I thought that was the default as well. According to the second answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476329/asp-net-invalid-postback-or-callback-argument, this is caused when modifying a list. In my case, I'm adding a single item to the control and then *selecting the new item*. Could you please try selecting the added item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I was able to eliminate this error by creating a custom DropDownList control like this:

```
public class DropDownListNoEventValidation : DropDownList
{
}
```

This apparently creates a control called `DropDownListNoEventValidation` without the attribute `SupportsEventValidation`.

The result is elimination of the error I was getting before. Unfortunately, it appears ASP.NET does not recognize the selected value if it is an item that was dynamically added to the list. I'm still working on that problem.

**UPDATE:**

I ended up using a `<select>` element without `runat="server"`. This was a bit more work, but seemed the most straight forward way to get this to work as expected.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Have you tried using <select runat="server"> to make server-side access to it more easily?

Comment: I didn't try that. I guess I could. I don't really know off the top of my head how much server-side functionality there is with this tag.

Comment: Well if it ain't broke - don't fix it :) if your solution worked for your - go with it.