# handle asp.net imagebutton in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a webform that contains a listview like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="SlidesListView" runat="server" OnItemCommand="SlidesListView_ItemCommand">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" style="display: inline-block" />
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="SlideDiv">
                        <div>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ChangeDescriptionImageButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/Change.png" CommandArgument="<%# Eval("ID") %>" CommandName="Change" AlternateText="Change" ToolTip="Change" />
                            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" CssClass="MiniSliderPic" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImagePath") %>' AlternateText='<%#Eval("Description") %>' ToolTip='<%#Eval("Description") %>' />
                            <p><%#Eval("Description").ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>").Replace("\n", "<br />") %></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </span>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:ListView>
```

and codebehind:

```
protected void SlidesListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int ID = 0;
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "Change":
                ID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
              break;
```

}
}

but when I try to open this webform , I face this error:

*An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 
the server tag is not well formed*

and asp:ImageButton tag get red.why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
CommandArgument="<%# Eval("ID") %>"
```

To this:

```
 CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
```

BTW, I don't think you can use imagebutton this way. It will fire it's won OnCommand rather than ListView's ItemCommand. Consider using a linkbutton with image inside it.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ChangeDescriptionLinkButton" runat="server"
    CommandName="Change"
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' >
    <img src="~/Image/Change.png" alt="Change" />Change
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: oh,what a silly wrong.thanks alot. now I face 'invalid postback or callback...' error ,is there any way to solve it without using EnableEventValidation="false"? it's reduce secrity. (I have to create a new question about it?)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does. See here [asp.net: Invalid postback or callback argument](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7476352/690329).

Comment: but I removed EnableEventValidation="false" ,and it still works fine.

Comment: Then you don't have to worry!