# ASP.NET Invalid postback or callback argument Error on Dropdownlist with AutoPostBack = true

Tags: asp.net

I have this code in my aspx page :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="campagnes" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  ></asp:DropDownList>
```

I am filling the DropDownList with :

```
foreach (DataRow DR in DS.Tables["CAMPAGNES"].Rows) {
     campagnes.Items.Add(new ListItem(DR.Field<string>("LIBELLE").ToString(), DR.Field<int>("STATUSGROUP")));
}
```

The DropDownList is filled with the data i wanted to add but if i select an item in the list, i get this error :

"Invalid postback or callback argument ..."

I have no idea what does it mean and how to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly new myself to C#, but I normally find most postback errors can be solved by wrapping your call to your populate drop-down list method with.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

     if (!Page.IsPostBack)
     { 
      //your dropdown list code
     }
  }
```

Failing that my next attempt would be to put your dropdown in an update panel to avoid a postback all together.

[see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx)

Comment: I was already wrapping it with "!IsPostBack" but i still had the error. I have seen that update panel might be a solution but i haven't used it yet. I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: have your tried to disable event validation to see if that's what's causing the problem? (EnableEventValidation="false") I definitely wouldn't leave it off, but you would know that was the problem, this question might help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476329/asp-net-invalid-postback-or-callback-argument)

Comment: Again, thank you for your help. Using "update panel" is solving the problem.