# ASP.NET button inside a modal not triggering click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

Getting this on submit button click

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or
>   callback events originate from the server control that originally
>   rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager. RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation."

Click event is not occurring.

Please Help!

Comment: Please include some code.. there are multiple reasons for this, but try what it's telling you, add EnableEventValidation="true" on the @Page directive...

Comment: Check this post. It can help hou: [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476329/asp-net-invalid-postback-or-callback-argument)