# IIS cannot redirect login page | Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I have a problem with my ASP.NET login page that running trought IIS web server. the message problem "Invalid postback or callback argument" after clicking login that cannot be redirect for "admin main page".
But if that login page running with Visual Studio, it working that redirect normaly How I can do for IIS configuration or my login code?

this is my login page code (default page) :

```
 KoneksiServer()
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1))
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
    txt_user.Focus()
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        If Session("username") <> "" And Session("Login") <> "" Then
            Response.Redirect("~/page/Admin/index.aspx")
        End If
        If ((Not (Request.Cookies("UserName")) Is Nothing) _
                    AndAlso (Not (Request.Cookies("Password")) Is Nothing)) Then
            txt_user.Text = Request.Cookies("UserName").Value
            txt_password.Attributes("value") = Request.Cookies("Password").Value
        End If

    End If
```

and this is error page if trought IIS :

[image]
Thank You,

Comment: Can you tell us more about exactly what this "login page" is, and how it's supposed to work?  Can you post any code?  Can you copy/paste an exact error message?  Do you see an error in the IIS logs?  Please update your post with more details.

Comment: @paulsm4 I have been update my post, thank you for your post

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: As a "last resort", you can disable event validation: `<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" %>`.  But you should continue trying to find the "root cause" of the validation error and fix it, first.  Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228969/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476329) for suggestions.