# Error in button click event in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem button click event in asp.net C#.
Here is my exception.

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Comment: Can you provide example code that exhibits current issue? As your starting point, read [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476329/asp-net-invalid-postback-or-callback-argument) for possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your .aspx file and build solution again.

```
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Sorry for my reply is too late.